# Why does my song keep on resetting when I pause it?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, libvlc

I am making an audio player and am running into this issue. My song always resets when I hit the pause button.

Here is the code for the pause/play button.

```py
s = 0
PauseState = 1 # is a 1 if paused
PlaySwitch = 0 # Shifts through Play and Pause state
ListSwitch = 0 # Visability of the Song List
window = Tk()

## -- Button Subprograms -- ##
def PlayBtn(): # Control for the play button
    global PlaySwitch
    global s
    global PauseState
    if PauseState == 0:
        pass
    else:
        s = vlc.MediaPlayer(SongList.get(ACTIVE))

    if PlaySwitch == 0:
        Bplay.config(image = Ppause)
        PlaySwitch = 1
        s.play()
        PauseState = 0
    else:
        Bplay.config(image = Pplay)
        PlaySwitch = 0
        s.pause()
        PauseState = 1
    print(f"Play/Pause Button Val: {PlaySwitch}")
    window.update()
```

Comment: Your code is not testable. We need to be able to run the code as is and see the problem. You are missing all of the GUI code involved.

Comment: I suspect `s = vlc.MediaPlayer(SongList.get('active'))` is the problem due to how your if/else statement is called.

Comment: @Mike-SMT what do I have to do instead? I need it to update what song it is playing when they select the song from a ListBox

Comment: I cant really say until I can test your code. Please create a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: What is the difference of purpose of `PlaySwitch` and `PauseState`?  Seems they are the same.  For your posted code, `PauseState` should not be set to 1 when `PlaySwitch` is 1.  `PauseState` is set to 1 when song is changed.